# Typescript Class-Validator Contains multiple strings (IsEmail)

Tags: javascript, typescript, class-validator, typescript-decorator

I have been using the class-validator decorator library to validate dto objects and would like to create a domain whitelist for the @IsEmail decorator. The library includes a @Contains decorator, which can be used for a single string (seed), but I would like to input an array of valid strings instead. Is this possible?

**current**

```
  @Contains('@mydomain.com')
  @IsEmail()
  public email: string;
```

**desired**

```
  @Contains(['@mydomain, @yourdomain, @wealldomain, @fordomain'])
  @IsEmail()
  public email: string;
```

If this is not possible, I would appreciate any direction on how to implement a custom decorator which serves this purpose.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you not use `@ArrayContains(values: any[])`?

Answer (score 0):

Consider this example:

```js
const Contains = <Domain extends `@${string}`, Domains extends Domain[]>(domains: [...Domains]) =>
    (target: Object, propertyKey: string) => {
        let value: string;
        const getter = () => value
        const setter = function (newVal: Domain) {
            if (domains.includes(newVal)) {
                value = newVal;
            }
            else {
                throw Error(`Domain should be one of ${domains.join()}`)
            }
        };
        Object.defineProperty(target, propertyKey, {
            get: getter,
            set: setter
        });
    }

class Greeter {
    @Contains(['@mydomain', '@wealldomain'])
    greeting: string;
    constructor(message: string) {
        this.greeting = message;
    }

}

const ok = new Greeter('@mydomain'); // ok
const error = new Greeter('234'); // runtime error
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=99#code/FDDGHsDsGcBcAIDCVYEMCWN4F54B4ARcAWw0ngFMAPWCyAE2ngAMABAEgG84AnTAcwC%20zADTwipTE2q0GTCWQDaAXQB8ACnoky0AFzxFAOmMKpygJQ5VweLfjq0PfhVj6A8gCMAVhVCwxAA484AEUPLAAngDSFBH6vAKW2KrwnDZ2GQA2LvAAbqiZAK4U8bB8kPwA3OkZthAwCM6wtDw49kkp%20UUUNbX1cPDQLi1tAGaFkH7oUPaQFADuAGoF%20qaQlmm1W-Doo-ZakjCGmKBF9BTQ6nNLBeYbvdu1XcVt18uZ1Y8Zgg-bFJlDVK-L7wWAAC2C83gAFEeMEeOpmGtBmDwIVMvR4B4KPAoDjwHsuAcdIYvOBMOpzMJzMDaj9HoJPttPD4-IZzqNMBQAArBULhCIOVBOFyBPlhSIxCJiTYg%20BNfRNFoiWkZIauQbDMK0wTmJm2H5gTKoaBMADiPAoLjCQIyrGQkDQUnUigA5KxiBFiZhXWJ3fMKAUMdofRZevxLS4BKVylVev0yoU-OAEcQLtBUM4Y4lbdtwehoIYI1bYAI2mnTZmKPr4IbDQncQBrV4LeAWkthdTuz3eyCuvXwAD0g6bYCgAzC8JbUPb1oRroATABmAAs-cqQ5HPAmpbTlDhKZAQA)

If you provide invalid email domain it will trigger runtime error. It is up to you how you want to implement validation logic. It might be not necessary a runtime error